# Signpost callback works on Android Emulator with API 10 but not API 15 or 16

Tags: android, callback, signpost

I believe that I have correctly coded and setup the Signpost call to Twitter.  It all works perfectly fine when running on API 10 (through Emulator and actual phone).  But when I try the exact same apk on API 15 or 16, the callback doesn't work at all.  Instead of returning me to my app, it sends me to another webpage that says the page is not available and identifies my callback URL + oauth token.  I have

- set android:launchMode="singleInstance" for the activity
- set the android:scheme and android:host to match the callback URL passed to     retrieveRequestToken
- overridden onNewIntent

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".TimelineActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleInstance">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

      <!-- Used for OAuth callback -->
      <intent-filter >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
          <data
              android:scheme="x-AbcdEfg41-oauth-twitter"
              android:host="callback" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```

onNewIntent looks like this:

```
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "intent:  " + intent);

    //check if this is a callback from OAuth
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "callback:  " + uri.getPath());
        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
        Log.d(TAG, "verifier:  " + verifier);

        new RetrieveAccessTokenTask().execute(verifier);
    }
```

And my auth call looks like this:

```
try {
      authUrl = this.mProvider.retrieveRequestToken(this.mConsumer, OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
      Log.d(TAG, authUrl);
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And my logcat looks OK although I'm bit suspicious about "Emulator without GPU emulation detected" simply because I don't see that when I run on API 10:

```
12-07 04:48:31.428: I/TimelineApplication(754): onCreate
12-07 04:48:31.598: I/TimelineActivity(754): onCreate(). Starting authorizaion.
12-07 04:48:31.658: I/dalvikvm(754): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-07 04:48:31.678: I/dalvikvm(754): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-07 04:48:31.758: D/TimelineActivity(754): OAuthAuthorizeTask.doInBackground()
12-07 04:48:31.857: D/gralloc_goldfish(754): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-07 04:48:32.968: D/dalvikvm(754): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 3% free 12797K/13063K, paused 7ms+6ms
12-07 04:48:33.907: D/TimelineApplication(754): https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=QepbZdXy2uiDFt7vrwvwq72Wl1S2IzsZywCPHwx8jTk
12-07 04:48:33.968: D/TimelineApplication(754): oAuthAuthorize() has finished
12-07 04:48:34.139: D/TimelineActivity(754): OAuthAuthorizeTask.onPostExecute()
12-07 04:48:34.368: D/TimelineActivity(754): the result is NULL
```